# Does Ubuntu require reinstalling?

Tags: 14.04, reinstall

Sorry for newbie question, I've been using Windows for over 20 years now and simultaneously OS X for last 5 years and I'm shocked the OS X is still working like 5 years ago while I really HAVE to reinstall Windows every 2-4 years.

I know the difference lies in the user usually but note I'm rather an advanced Windows user (I'm way more experienced with it than with OS X for sure), I've always been nice to my Windows (I never got a single virus infection in these 20 years, I try to "install" only portable/standalone software etc.), yet I still feel my Windows is WAY slower a few years after fresh reinstall. I don't feel it AT ALL with OS X.

Is Ubuntu the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu works different than Windows. Ubuntu for example doesn't have a registry so less unused stuff is collected. There's no direct need to reinstall Ubuntu regularly although it won't hurt things. Since there are regular new releases of ubuntu in a certain way you're refreshing from time to time.

Ubuntu does not really require virus scanners because there are no known viruses (but sometimes there are vulnerabilities) therefore ubuntu is not slowed down by a virusscanner.

Comment: I knew Ubuntu would be much "closer" to OS X than Windows, updating the OS doesn't bother me (actually I've updated from Mavericks to Yosemite a few weeks ago and it got even faster, while I'd never update Windows without formating the C drive). So I guess Ubuntu should be as stable as OS X and wouldn't need reinstalling every few years or so? How about drivers, are they also easily removable? I think the biggest difference when it comes to reinstalling lies within drivers, everything works like a charm on closed OS X but Windows supports so much hardware drivers often mess things up.

Comment: Ubuntu is built around the Linux kernel and so is/was OS X. They're about equally stable. Unlike Windows, Ubuntu rarely requires seperate drivers. A lot of hardware is recognized 'out of the box' by Ubuntu. If there's an additional driver required then it has to meet Ubuntu's standards so you can assume it is stable.